# Change master page for nested master page at runtime?

Tags: .net, asp.net, master-pages

I have 2 master page: master1.master, master2.master
And i have another nested master page nestedMaster.master that nested from master1.master.

Question:
How can i change nested master page file of nestedMaster.master at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the [Page_PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) [event](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-vb) of content page and set `MasterPageFile` property.

```
 public void Page_PreInit()
 {
   this.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/master2.master";
 }
```

Comment: As i know this event is not availabe in master page. How can i change master page of nestedMaster.master in code behide of this file (nestedMaster.master.cs)?

Comment: @MinhNguyen - Yes that's true. You need to handle the content page event.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AdminBasePage : BasePage 
{ 
     protected override void SetMasterPageFile() 
     { 
          Page.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/PathToMaster/Site.Master"; 
     } 
}
```

http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/nested-master-pages-vb#